# Userdata script not running in ubuntu server while creating with cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, aws-cloudformation, user-data

Sorry for asking repeated and old question .My code does not run a userdata shell script . My userdata property is a parameter which will given while create a stack .
my code is

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Description": "AWS CloudFormation Sample Template",
"Parameters": {
    "UserData": {
        "Description": "User data",
        "Type": "String"
    }
},
"Resources": {
    "EC2Instance": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Properties": {
            "KeyName": {
                "Ref": "KeyName"
            },
            "InstanceType": {
                "Ref": "InstanceType"
            },
            "ImageId": {
                "Ref": "ImageId"
            },
            "SecurityGroups": [
                {
                    "Ref": "EC2SecurityGroup"
                }
            ],
            "UserData": {
                "Fn::Base64": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        "",
                        [
                            "#!/bin/bash",
                            "\n",
                            {
                                "Ref": "UserData"
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I gave the following shell command in userdata parameter

```
"apt-get update","\n","apt-get install -y apache2","\n","apt-get install -y php","\n"
```

I can't know whether my userdata scricpt is right or not,
It doesn't show any error while creating a stack , It creates a instance successfully .
After instance creation I checked apache2 and php not installed in the instance .
can anyone find what is wrong in my code ?

Comment: Looks like userdata parameter is not valid script, this won't get split as an array, but rather be treated like a string, try passing `apt-get update\n update-get install -y apache2.....` as an UserData CloudFormation parameter

Comment: this user data  parameter       `apt-get update\n apt-get install -y apache2\n apt-get install -y php`       does not working @toske   Is there any changes in my JSON code

Comment: What does the system log show?  Also check the user data on the instance from aws console. Is it properly formatted?

Comment: Also note the "/n" character in the CFN. That appears to be invalid.

Comment: I am giving  `apt-get update\n apt-get install -y apache2\n apt-get install -y php`  as a user data parameter. The user data in aws console is look like as    `#/bin/bash -xe
apt-get update\n apt-get install -y apache2\n apt-get install -y php`  and also updated my json code   "/n" to "\n"  then what is my problem ?  @RodrigoM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It accepts the following userdata , and its install all softwares which is given in following scripts.

```
apt-get update;apt-get install -y apache2;apt-get install -y php;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this UserData block. UserData is renamed to to UData to exclude naming conflicts. In this case UData should be "apt-get update; apt-get install -y apache2 php;"

```
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Description": "AWS CloudFormation Sample Template",
"Parameters": {
    "UData": {
        "Description": "User data",
        "Type": "String"
    }
},
"Resources": {
    "EC2Instance": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Properties": {
            "KeyName": {
                "Ref": "KeyName"
            },
            "InstanceType": {
                "Ref": "InstanceType"
            },
            "ImageId": {
                "Ref": "ImageId"
            },
            "SecurityGroups": [
                {
                    "Ref": "EC2SecurityGroup"
                }
            ],
            "UserData": {
                "Fn::Base64": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        "",
                        [
                            "#!/bin/bash\n",
                            "echo \">>>>>>>>>>>>> UPDATE <<<<<<<<<<<<<\"\n",
                            "export USR_DATA='", { "Ref": "UData" }, "'\n",
                            "echo $USR_DATA\n",
                            "echo $USR_DATA > user_data.sh\n",
                            "chmod +x user_data.sh\n",
                            "source user_data.sh\n",
                            "echo \">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<\"\n"
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

User data is also logged in /var/log/cloud-init-output.log
And output from that log could really help on debug.

Comment: thank you , Its working good.But I need to achieve the same through userdata parameter , whats wrong with my json code or userdata parameter. otherwise please give some idea about giving parameters for user data in cloudformation template  @Mareks Pikalovs

Comment: @ArunKumar you may want to consider building your cloudformation with higher-level tools such as `cfndsl` (ruby dsl for cloudformation). This way you can have ruby variable defining user data, but hardcoded in compiled template.

Comment: we can give user data like `apt-get update;apt-get install -y apache2;apt-get install -y php;`  Its working . thanks all